# Error in Xcode archieve and build step at azure devops pipeline

Tags: ios, xcode

I have azure pipeline for ios after an update to xcode and macos agent version it is not working.
xcode version is now 11
I'm using macos 13 microsoft hosted agent
although I have even updated APPle certificate and provisioning profile and it wont even work

at xcode build step I'm facing below error
note: Building targets in dependency order

```
/Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: error: nanopb does not support provisioning profiles. nanopb does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile CivicaDistribution2023To2024 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: error: MSAL does not support provisioning profiles. MSAL does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile CivicaDistribution2023To2024 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'MSAL' from project 'Pods')
```

warning: Run script build phase 'Copy `your text`www directory' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'CarelinkGo' from project 'CarelinkGo')
/Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods`your text`')
/Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: error: Pods-CarelinkGo does not support provisioning profiles. Pods-CarelinkGo does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile CivicaDistribution2023To2024 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'Pods-CarelinkGo' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstanceID' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: error: Protobuf does not support provisioning profiles. Protobuf does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile CivicaDistribution2023To2024 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseMessaging' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.2.99. (in target 'GoogleToolboxForMac' from project 'Pods')
/Users/runner/work/1/s/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: error: GoogleToolboxForMac does not support provisioning profiles. GoogleToolboxForMac does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile CivicaDistribution2023To2024 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'GoogleToolboxForMac' from project 'Pods')
** BUILD FAILED **

```
\##\[debug\]Exit code 65 received from tool '/usr/bin/xcodebuild'
\##\[debug\]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/usr/bin/xcodebuild'
\##\[debug\]task result: Failed
\##\[error\]Error: The process '/usr/bin/xcodebuild' failed with exit code 65
```

At xcode archieve step getting same error of exit code 65.

PLEASE DO LET ME KNOW THAT WHAT CAN I DO ? NOT GETTING SOLUTION FOR ABOVE ISSUE

I've updated apple certificate and provisioning profile still now working.

With some article I've added following script before xcode step

```
$PodPath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/platforms/ios/Podfile"
$PodUpdatedPath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/platforms/ios/Podfile.updated"

Get-Content $PodPath | ForEach-Object {$\_ -Replace 'use_frameworks!', "use_frameworks!`n`npost_install do |installer|`n  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|`n    target.build_configurations.each do |config|`n      config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = `"`"`n      config.build_settings\['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'\] = `"NO`"`n      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = `"NO`"`n    end`n  end`nend"} | Set-Content $PodUpdatedPath;

Get-Content $PodUpdatedPath | Set-Content $PodPath

$PodPath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/platforms/ios/Podfile"
$PodUpdatedPath = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/platforms/ios/Podfile.updated"

Get-Content $PodPath | ForEach-Object {$\_ -Replace 'use_frameworks!', "use_frameworks!`n`npost_install do |installer|`n  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|`n flutter_additional_ios_build_settings.each do `n   target.build_configurations.each do |config|`n      config.build_settings\['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'\] = `"11.0`"`n      end`n  end\`nend"} | Set-Content $PodUpdatedPath;

Get-Content $PodUpdatedPath | Set-Content $PodPath
```

Still is not working